# c# json merge only values (ignore missing fields)

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I'm using NewtonsoftJson library, I'm trying to merge two json objects. But the desired result is not usual merge, but more like add or update. For example I have the following objects:

Object 1:

```
{
  'FirstName': 'John',
  'LastName': 'Smith',
  'Enabled': false,
  'Roles': [ 'User' ]
}
```

Object 2:

```
{
  'FirstName': 'Harry',
  'Enabled': true,
  'Age': 29,
  'Roles': [ 'User', 'Admin' ]
}
```

And the result should looks like :

```
{
  "FirstName": "Harry",
  "LastName": "Smith",
  "Enabled": true,
  'Roles': [ 'User', 'Admin' ]
}
```

Without AGE field. I just want to update values for existing fields and I want to ignore new (not existing in first one) fields - in this case , field : Age.
Looks like the library is not providing such behaviour.

For custom implementation it looks really hard,because of different types at least. For example in one case it could be just a number, in other case it could be array etc.
Any ideas ?

Comment: but what about `FirstName`? how `Harry` comes to result why not `John`?

Comment: For the array part : do you want to *merge* the arrays, or just *replace* the whole array ? For instance, if Object 1 had `'Roles': [ 'Use', 'Other' ]` , what would be the expected result ?

Comment: One option would be to deserialize the 2 json strings into C# objects, do what you need to do and then serialize the result object.

Comment: @ershoaib becasue the second object provide updates for existing (old) values in the first object. Same for `enabled` field

Comment: You probably need to read both JSON data _(see [this example](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadJsonWithJsonTextReader.htm))_, update the data manually and then save it. There is no automated function for you as far as I know.

Comment: You can't do this as Json.Net doesn't allow you to pass an existing object in to be updated. You would have to implement your own deserialization code.

Answer (score 2):

You can list all the properties from the first object and compare with the second. If it finds the property in the second object take the value otherwise take it from first object:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var obj = JObject.Parse(@"{'FirstName': 'John',
                               'LastName': 'Smith',
                               'Enabled': false,
                               'Roles': [ 'User' ]}");

    var obj2 = JObject.Parse(@"{'FirstName': 'Harry',
                                'Enabled': true,
                                'Age': 29,
                                'Roles': [ 'User', 'Admin' ]}");

    var propertyNames = obj.Properties().Select(p => p.Name);

    var result = new JObject();

    foreach (var property in propertyNames)
    {
        JToken value;
        if (!obj2.TryGetValue(property, out value))
            value = obj.GetValue(property);

        result.Add(property, value);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might want to deserialize Json into `JObject` and as it implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<>>` you could simply iterate it with a foreach loop:

```
JObject obj;
JObject updateWith;

foreach (var token in updateWith)
{
   if (obj.ContainsKey(token.Key))
   {
      obj[token.Key] = token.Value;
   }
}
```